# Exception_Access_Violation - external device-API - JNI

Tags: java, c++, exception, java-native-interface, access-violation

I am trying to call native methods from a c++-project via JNI. Unfortunately I am getting an "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" [1].

I have debugged my code and found out that the exception is thrown because of the following lines of code. The ones with comments / calling methods from another class (.header files included).

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_gwap_control_Coordinates_start_1tracking
(JNIEnv *, jclass){

char url[20] = "tet-tcp://127.0.0.1";
comp_error_code error_code;
comp_device* device;

// Create an device instance.
device = comp_create(url, &error_code);

// Start the event loop.
comp_run_event_loop_on_internal_thread(device, 0, 0);
```

[...]

```
// Track for a while
XSLEEP(20000);
```

[...]

Compiling the project as .exe and running it in commandline works fine. When compiling it as .dll and including it into my Java-project, the exception is thrown. If said lines of code are commented out, the exception is not thrown.

From that I conclude that my cpp code as well as my java code is correct. I guess the problem might be that the (complete) native code is not fully included into the (generally working) project when compiled to the library file (?).

The code itself is for getting the output data (coordinates) of an peripheral controller. Therefore I edited an existing (c/cpp-)SDK to use the data in my java application.

The system and software I am using is specified at the end of [1], UAC is turned off.

I would be grateful for every hint or idea of how to fix my problem.
Thanks in advance!

[1]

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000000c8fc, pid=2804, tid=4248
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000000000000c8fc
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000001f8e800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4248, stack(0x0000000002090000,0x0000000002190000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x000000000000c8fc

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000218f4e8, RBX=0x0000000016180850, RCX=0x0000000000004e20, RDX=0x000000000218f5b0
RSP=0x000000000218f4b8, RBP=0x000000000218f5a0, RSI=0x00007ff71f0e78ec, RDI=0x000000000218f4fc
R8 =0x0000000000000004, R9 =0x0000000001f885e0, R10=0x00000000022a4b42, R11=0x000000005b479df0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000016180850, R14=0x000000000218f5b8, R15=0x0000000001f8e800
RIP=0x000000000000c8fc, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000218f4b8)
0x000000000218f4b8:   00007ff71f0e13ca cccccccccccccccc
0x000000000218f4c8:   cccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccc
0x000000000218f4d8:   cccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccc
0x000000000218f4e8:   3a7063742d746574 2e302e3732312f2f
0x000000000218f4f8:   cccccccc00312e30 cccccccccccccccc
0x000000000218f508:   cccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccc
0x000000000218f518:   00002b992fc756f2 cccccccccccccccc
0x000000000218f528:   00000000ffffffff 0000000001f8e800
0x000000000218f538:   00000000022a4b6e 0000000001f8e9e0
0x000000000218f548:   000000000218f5b0 000000000218f610
0x000000000218f558:   00000000022a489c 000000000218f560
0x000000000218f568:   0000000016180850 000000000218f5b8
0x000000000218f578:   0000000016180b18 0000000000000000
0x000000000218f588:   0000000016180850 0000000000000000
0x000000000218f598:   000000000218f5c0 000000000218f600
0x000000000218f5a8:   0000000002297380 00000000d9b12f60 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000000000c8fc)
0x000000000000c8dc:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000000218f4e8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000001f8e800
RBX=0x0000000016180850 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000004e20 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000218f5b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000001f8e800
RSP=0x000000000218f4b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000001f8e800
RBP=0x000000000218f5a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000001f8e800
RSI=0x00007ff71f0e78ec is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000000218f4fc is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000001f8e800
R8 =0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000001f885e0 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000022a4b42 is at code_begin+834 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x00000000022a4800, 0x00000000022a5140]  2368 bytes
R11=0x000000005b479df0 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000016180850 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000218f5b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000001f8e800
R15=0x0000000001f8e800 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000002090000,0x0000000002190000],  sp=0x000000000218f4b8,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x000000000000c8fc

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  gwap.control.Coordinates.start_tracking()V+0
j  gwap.control.ControllerMain.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000017fa0800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4276, stack(0x0000000018380000,0x0000000018480000)]
  0x0000000016729000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3340, stack(0x0000000017e80000,0x0000000017f80000)]
  0x0000000016720800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3296, stack(0x0000000017d80000,0x0000000017e80000)]
  0x000000001671e800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4208, stack(0x0000000017c80000,0x0000000017d80000)]
  0x000000001671d000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4808, stack(0x0000000017b80000,0x0000000017c80000)]
  0x000000001671c800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5960, stack(0x0000000017a80000,0x0000000017b80000)]
  0x0000000002284000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3288, stack(0x0000000017980000,0x0000000017a80000)]
  0x000000000227b000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5664, stack(0x0000000017880000,0x0000000017980000)]
=>0x0000000001f8e800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4248, stack(0x0000000002090000,0x0000000002190000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000166e5800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000017780000,0x0000000017880000] [id=1492]
  0x0000000017fad800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000018480000,0x0000000018580000] [id=4744]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 505K [0x00000000d9b00000, 0x00000000d9d00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 512K, 20% used [0x00000000d9b00000,0x00000000d9b1a4e8,0x00000000d9b80000)
  from space 512K, 78% used [0x00000000d9b80000,0x00000000d9be4010,0x00000000d9c00000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000d9c80000,0x00000000d9c80000,0x00000000d9d00000)
 ParOldGen       total 117248K, used 8K [0x000000008d000000, 0x0000000094280000, 0x00000000d9b00000)
  object space 117248K, 0% used [0x000000008d000000,0x000000008d002000,0x0000000094280000)
 Metaspace       used 2366K, capacity 4486K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 264K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011650000,0x00000000119f0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000111e8000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005ba213b0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012060000, 0x0000000013d20000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000013d20000, 0x00000000159e0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000810000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1103Kb max_used=1103Kb free=244656Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002290000, 0x0000000002500000, 0x0000000011290000]
 total_blobs=253 nmethods=29 adapters=140
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.091 Thread 0x0000000016729000   25       3       java.lang.String::startsWith (72 bytes)
Event: 0.091 Thread 0x0000000016729000 nmethod 25 0x00000000023a11d0 code [0x00000000023a1340, 0x00000000023a1670]
Event: 0.091 Thread 0x0000000016729000   26       3       java.lang.String::indexOf (7 bytes)
Event: 0.091 Thread 0x0000000016729000 nmethod 26 0x00000000023a1850 code [0x00000000023a19c0, 0x00000000023a1bc8]
Event: 0.092 Thread 0x0000000016729000   27       3       java.io.WinNTFileSystem::normalize (143 bytes)
Event: 0.092 Thread 0x0000000016729000 nmethod 27 0x00000000023a1c50 code [0x00000000023a1e40, 0x00000000023a2648]
Event: 0.092 Thread 0x0000000016729000   28       3       java.util.HashMap::getNode (148 bytes)
Event: 0.093 Thread 0x0000000016729000 nmethod 28 0x00000000023a29d0 code [0x00000000023a2ba0, 0x00000000023a3528]
Event: 0.093 Thread 0x0000000016729000   29       3       java.lang.String::equals (81 bytes)
Event: 0.093 Thread 0x0000000016729000 nmethod 29 0x00000000023a3810 code [0x00000000023a39a0, 0x00000000023a3ef0]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 0.083 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 512K [0x00000000d9b00000, 0x00000000d9c80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 512K, 100% used [0x00000000d9b00000,0x00000000d9b80000,0x00000000d9b80000)
  from space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000d9c00000,0x00000000d9c00000,0x00000000d9c80000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000d9b80000,0x00000000d9b80000,0x00000000d9c00000)
 ParOldGen       total 117248K, used 0K [0x000000008d000000, 0x0000000094280000, 0x00000000d9b00000)
  object space 117248K, 0% used [0x000000008d000000,0x000000008d000000,0x0000000094280000)
 Metaspace       used 2170K, capacity 4480K, committed 4480K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 244K, capacity 384K, committed 384K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 0.084 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 400K [0x00000000d9b00000, 0x00000000d9d00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000d9b00000,0x00000000d9b00000,0x00000000d9b80000)
  from space 512K, 78% used [0x00000000d9b80000,0x00000000d9be4010,0x00000000d9c00000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000d9c80000,0x00000000d9c80000,0x00000000d9d00000)
 ParOldGen       total 117248K, used 8K [0x000000008d000000, 0x0000000094280000, 0x00000000d9b00000)
  object space 117248K, 0% used [0x000000008d000000,0x000000008d002000,0x0000000094280000)
 Metaspace       used 2170K, capacity 4480K, committed 4480K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 244K, capacity 384K, committed 384K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (4 events):
Event: 0.039 Thread 0x0000000001f8e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d9b10868) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u5\2488\hotspot\src\çò;Ô¤?
Event: 0.039 Thread 0x0000000001f8e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d9b10af8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u5\2488\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jnì¨!'×µ?
Event: 0.085 Thread 0x0000000001f8e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d9b096c0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u5\2488\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1248]
Event: 0.091 Thread 0x0000000001f8e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d9b11e08) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u5\2488\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1248]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.090 loading class java/security/UnresolvedPermission
Event: 0.090 loading class java/security/UnresolvedPermission done
Event: 0.090 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection
Event: 0.090 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection done
Event: 0.090 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper
Event: 0.091 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper done
Event: 0.091 loading class gwap/control/Coordinates
Event: 0.091 loading class gwap/control/Coordinates done
Event: 0.091 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper
Event: 0.091 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6ba360000 - 0x00007ff6ba394000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007fff97cb0000 - 0x00007fff97e5a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007fff96080000 - 0x00007fff961ba000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007fff95420000 - 0x00007fff9552f000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007fff93c30000 - 0x00007fff93cb8000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007fff90800000 - 0x00007fff9084f000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007fff96580000 - 0x00007fff96627000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007fff94e00000 - 0x00007fff94e2b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007fff962e0000 - 0x00007fff96331000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007fff95880000 - 0x00007fff959f1000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007fff96340000 - 0x00007fff964b8000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007fff96890000 - 0x00007fff97cb0000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007fff94a00000 - 0x00007fff94a1e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007fff95fd0000 - 0x00007fff96075000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007fff91bb0000 - 0x00007fff91bcb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007fff95ba0000 - 0x00007fff95cd6000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007fff95ce0000 - 0x00007fff95d37000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007fff95550000 - 0x00007fff95726000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007fff95730000 - 0x00007fff95874000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007fff95020000 - 0x00007fff95034000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007fff93660000 - 0x00007fff936ff000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007fff96520000 - 0x00007fff96554000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007fff95a00000 - 0x00007fff95b39000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007fff929a0000 - 0x00007fff92bfa000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17031_none_6242a4b3ecbb55a1\COMCTL32.dll
0x000000005cd60000 - 0x000000005ce32000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000005b270000 - 0x000000005ba9a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007fff93270000 - 0x00007fff93279000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007fff91dd0000 - 0x00007fff91def000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007fff96560000 - 0x00007fff96567000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007fff961c0000 - 0x00007fff96218000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007fff91da0000 - 0x00007fff91dca000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007fff96570000 - 0x00007fff96579000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007fff953d0000 - 0x00007fff9541a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007fff93eb0000 - 0x00007fff93ed6000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000000005cd50000 - 0x000000005cd5f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\verify.dll
0x000000005cd20000 - 0x000000005cd48000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java.dll
0x000000005cd00000 - 0x000000005cd16000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff71f0e0000 - 0x00007ff71f0ef000     C:\Users\...\workspace\...\TrackingAPI.dll
0x00007fff74360000 - 0x00007fff743f6000     C:\Users\...\workspace\...\CompCore64.dll
0x00007fff8ecc0000 - 0x00007fff8ed67000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP110.dll
0x00007fff8ebe0000 - 0x00007fff8ecb4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR110.dll
0x00007fff925c0000 - 0x00007fff92748000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: gwap.control.ControllerMain
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\...\workspace\...\bin;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\eventbus.jar;C:\Users\..\workspace\...\lib\gluegen-rt.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\j-ogg-oggd.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\j-ogg-vorbisd.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jbullet.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jglfont-core.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jinput.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-blender.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-core.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-desktop.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-effects.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-jbullet.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-jogg.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-lwjgl-natives.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-lwjgl.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-networking.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-niftygui.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-openal-soft-natives-android.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-plugins.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-terrain.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jME3-testdata.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\joal.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\jogl-all.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\lwjgl.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\nifty-default-controls.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\nifty-examples.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\nifty-style-black.jar;C:\Users\...\workspace\...\lib\nifty.jar;C:\Users\...\
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Comp\Comp Device Controller\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\
USERNAME=...
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 21 Model 19 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 21 model 19 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 7535300k(5091636k free), swap 8714948k(5116720k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_05-b13), built on Mar 18 2014 01:08:39 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Tue Jul 01 13:41:40 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: If you compile your project as DLL - where do you call  `JNI_CreateJavaVM` and `DestroyJavaVM`? In DllMain on attach/detach or somewhere else?

Comment: @Constantin 
Actually I don't. I want to use my c++ code within my java application (not the Invocation API).
Therefore I wrote the java class "Coordinates" containing the methods with the "native" modifiers, created the headerfile and imported it into my c++-project. Which I then edited and compiled as a .dll (using VisualStudio2013 setting the "Configuration Type" to .dll). I only posted the code that doesn't work, the other JNIEXPORT-methods work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: VisualStudio (or I) did not change the configuration type to .dll correctly. Can be checked in the projectstandards tab in the preferences of the project.